# Middleware executing before Vuex Store restore from localstorage

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, persistence, vuex, nuxt.js

In nuxtjs project, I created an auth middleware to protect page.
and using vuex-persistedstate (also tried vuex-persist and nuxt-vuex-persist) to persist vuex store.

Everything is working fine when navigating from page to page, but when i refresh page or directly land to protected route, it redirect me to login page.

localStorage plugin

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState({
      key: 'store-key'
  })(store)
}
```

auth middleware

```
export default function ({ req, store, redirect, route }) {
    const userIsLoggedIn = !!store.state.auth.user
    if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
        return redirect(`/auth/login?redirect=${route.fullPath}`)
    }
    return Promise.resolve()
}
```

Comment: Also experiencing this. Did you make any progress?

Comment: @SeanRussell I fail in solving the issue, but found a bypass to this by creating a redirect page. In my case store data was located at localstorage of client side. So whenever we perform refresh, server try to locate the store data on server, thats by it. So i create a redirect page. and change the above function accordingly. Mail me at yashdeep.rajput019@gmail.com for code.

Comment: @auedbaki Can you post the solution here, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Current approach, we will always fail.

Actual Problem is Vuex Store can never be sync with server side Vuex store.

The fact is we only need data string to be sync with client and server (token).

We can achieve this synchronization with Cookies. because cookies automatically pass to every request from browser. So we don't need to set to any request. Either you just hit the URL from browser address bar or through navigation.

I recommend using module ['cookie-universal-nuxt'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) for set and remove of cookies.

For Setting cookie after login

```
this.$cookies.set('token', 'Bearer '+response.tokens.access_token, { path: '/', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 12 })
```

For Removing cookie on logout

```
this.$cookies.remove('token')
```

Please go through the docs for better understanding.

Also I'm using [@nuxt/http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/http) module for api request.

Now nuxt has a function called nuxtServerInit() in vuex store index file. You should use it to retrieve the token from request and set to http module headers.

```
async nuxtServerInit ({dispatch, commit}, {app, $http, req}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let token = app.$cookies.get('token')
        if(!!token) {
          $http.setToken(token, 'Bearer')
        }
        return resolve(true)
    })
  },
```

Below is my nuxt page level middleware

```
export default function ({app, req, store, redirect, route, context }) {
    if(process.server) {


        let token = app.$cookies.get('token')

        if(!token) {
            return redirect({path: '/auth/login', query: {redirect: route.fullPath, message: 'Token Not Provided'}})
        } else if(!isTokenValid(token.slice(7))) { // slice(7) used to trim Bearer(space)
            return redirect({path: '/auth/login', query: {redirect: route.fullPath, message: 'Token Expired'}})
        } 
        return Promise.resolve()
        
    }
    else {
        const userIsLoggedIn = !!store.state.auth.user
        if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
            return redirect({path: '/auth/login', query: {redirect: route.fullPath}})
            // return redirect(`/auth/login?redirect=${route.fullPath}`)
        } else if (!isTokenValid(store.state.auth.tokens.access_token)) {
            return redirect({path: '/auth/login', query: {redirect: route.fullPath, message: 'Token Expired'}})
            // return redirect(`/auth/login?redirect=${route.fullPath}&message=Token Expired`)
        } else if (isTokenValid(store.state.auth.tokens.refresh_token)) {
            return redirect(`/auth/refresh`)
        } else if (store.state.auth.user.role !== 'admin')
            return redirect(`/403?message=Not having sufficient permission`)
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
}
```

I have write different condition for with different source of token, as in code. On Server Process i'm getting token from cookies and on client getting token store. (Here we can also get from cookies)

After this you may get Some hydration issue because of store data binding in layout. To overcome this issue use `<no-ssr></no-ssr>` wrapping for such type of template code.

Comment: I am surprised that there are no more docs or comments on this subject. There is no way to access browser local storage on server side. Meaning, store access will always be undefined. My auth middleware is working with cookies as well. Of course, I am talking ssr mode for nuxt and not spa.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using this plugin [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) instead of the vuex-persist plugin. It seems there's some bug (or probably design architecture) in vuex-persist that's causing it.

Comment: This cannot be solve with client side solution. It happen because of absence of Vuex Store values at server side. Which is not possible with these libraries. You will experience when using asyncData Function which runs on server side.

Comment: Oh. That can be very true. But I experienced this issue using vuex-persist on the client side. On searching google, this page was the best result I could find so perhaps someone else who encounters the problem while using vuex-persist (before the issue is resolved in the plugin) can come across my comment and it will be of help. Besides there's nothing on servers in the question so I didn't know that.